# How to get String array from String instance variable in ArrayList of object?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, collections

I have the following class `Employee`:

```
Class Employee {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int Salary;
    /* getters and setters */
}
```

I built an `ArrayList` for this class and add some `Employee`s to it, as following:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
for (int x=1; x<=10; x++){
    Employee Newemp = new Employee();
    Newemp.setFirstname("firstname"+ i);
    Newemp.setLastname( "lastname"+ i);
    Newemp.setSalary( i * 1000);
    employees.add(Newemp); 
}
```

How do I get all the `Employee`s firstnames as a `String` array from the `Employee` `ArrayList` dynamically?

 
What I am asking is something like:

```
String employeesFirstname = employees.firstname;
```

Can I get this as a `String` array? or do I have to build it manually?

**this is not about how to access a value in ArryList, this is about how to get all values for specific property like firstname in ArrayList, as String array Type in android using java 7** .

Answer (score 4):

First of all, **your code does not add any `Employee`s to your list**. You first instantiate the list, then you create a handful of instances of `Employee`, but since they are not added to the list, they will no longer be accessible after the loop.

Explicitly add them to the list:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
for (int x=1; x<=10; x++){
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setFirstname("firstname"+ i);
    e.setLastname( "lastname"+ i);
    e.setSalary( i * 1000);
    employees.add(e);
}
```

---

Now you can access the properties of your `Employee`s in the list **by looping over the list**:

```
for(Employee e : employees) {
    // called once per Employee in the list
    System.out.println(e.getFirstName());
}
```

---

As a side node, **try to avoid single-character identifiers like `e`** from the very beginning. It may be obvious to you now that the `e` stands for 'employee', but not necessarily anymore in half a year, or even worse, to another developer. This problem gets even worse in bigger code bases.

Comment: thanks, I wrote my question quickly here and forgot to write .add method, anyway you get the idea, my question is not about accessing properties, it is as question titled: how to get String array variable from properties in ArrayList ?

Comment: If you are using Java 8, mapping the list to a String array with the first names is most likely best solved using the Stream API as described in the answers below.

Comment: I am using java 7 as default lang in android

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with using the stream API here. Something like employees.stream().map(Employees::getFirstname) .toArray() should do.

Comment: your answer is what I'm asking for, but I looking for answer in java 7 language.

Comment: I am unaware of any construction like this in Java 7 unfortunately. Lambda expressions are one of the greatest improvements towards Java 8 in my opinion, and this is one of the reasons. I'm afraid you'll just have to write it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Power of Lambda Expressions for that....

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> abc = new ArrayList<>();
    abc.add(new Employee());
    abc.add(new Employee());
    abc.add(new Employee());
    List<String> lastNamesList = abc.stream().map(Employee::getLastName)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        System.out.println(resultJava8);
}
```

Comment: in android (java 7) there is no .stream method in ArrayList class